# How do I get my function to take a float in addition to other arguments without throwing a TypeError?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Forgive me if this is too much info, I want to give as much context as possible in case the issue is being caused by something else in the script.

I'm new to Python/coding and I'm trying to create a function for later usage in a choose-your-own-adventure style game. The goal of the function is to be able to print strings that type out each letter one at a time for flavor, like a retro game.

I got the typing part working, but now I'm trying to give the function various parameters so that I can use it in different situations without boilerplating the entire script. I've added the option to output multiple lines on new lines and to output them over each other using \r.

The subject of my grief is trying to have variable speed. E.g. instead of outputting each letter with a delay of 0.04 seconds, maybe 0.1 seconds?

To do all this, I let the function take * arguments and check to see if the arguments include the key parameters which tell it what to do. All the arguments are made into a list so that I can pop() out the parameter arguments and proceed with just the strings.
The problem as I understand it is that now taking a float as an argument is throwing a TypeError in converting the arguments into a list.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

def say(*strings):
    strings = list(strings)

    # say([speed], string) Sets the print speed.
    #                      Default is 0.04s delay per letter.
    if strings[0] == int:
        print ""
        speed = strings[0]
        strings.pop(0)
    else:
        speed = 0.04

    # say(string, [1]) Prints the string(s) in a \n.
    if strings[-1] == 1:
        strings.pop()
        for x in strings:
            for letter in x:
                stdout.write(letter)
                sleep(speed)
            sleep(0.25)
            print ""

    # say(string, [2]) Prints the string(s) over the previous with \r.        
    elif strings[-1] == 2:
        strings.pop()
        lenx = 0
        for x in strings:
            nw_lenx = len(x)
            if nw_lenx < lenx:
                for l in range(0, (lenx - nw_lenx)):
                    x += " "
            lenx = nw_lenx

            for letter in x:
                stdout.write(letter)
                sleep(speed)

            sleep(0.25)
            stdout.write("\r")

    # say(string) Prints the string(s) without \n or \r.
    else:
        for x in strings:
            for letter in x:
                stdout.write(letter)
                sleep(speed)

say(
0.01,
"Example"
"Lorem Ipsum"
1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your first `if` block is checking to see whether your first argument passed in is equal to the `int` type itself. Instead, you should be checking if the *type* of your first argument is either an `int` or a `float`:

```
    # say([speed], string) Sets the print speed.
    #                      Default is 0.04s delay per letter.
    if type(strings[0]) is int or type(strings[0]) is float: # check type of argument
        print ""
        speed = strings[0]
        strings.pop(0)
    else:
        speed = 0.04
```

Because this argument wasn't popped from `strings`, when your code reaches the line `for letter in x`, it tries to iterate over a `float`, causing the `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`